# Camel : Impact on route execution when connection with external client closes unexpectedly

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix

We are exposing a SOAP/HTTP based camel-cxf web service where on receiving a request from 'Client-A', the route execution starts which involves calling one or more external web services lets say 'Server1', 'Server2' and 'Server3' in a sequentialmanner. In this case, we need to understand what happens to the execution of the route, when the original TCP connection with 'Client-A' is closed unexpectedly.

Will the route get executed successfully and an error is logged when it tries to send the final response?

Or will the route execution be stopped immediately as soon as the TCP connection is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture any errors during the route execution by camel's error handling mechanism and then define the policy on how you want to handle the exception, for example you can setup rules that state how many times to try redelivery, and the delay in between attempts, and so forth.
 For more information you can refer to this link: 
http://camel.apache.org/redeliverypolicy.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but let me explain the question a little better. lets say camel acts as a orchestration engine, 'ClientA' sends request to camel and camel starts calling 'ServerB', 'ServerC' and 'ServerD' one by one, now when the route execution is in progress lets say the connection with ''ClientA" is closed, now what happens to the route execution?

Comment: The route keeps running the operation until it is complete, however you might see *IOException* in the logs indicating that the client has gone away